# How to write conditional code that's compatible with both plain Python values and NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

For writing “piecewise functions” in Python, I'd normally use `if` (in either the control-flow or ternary-operator form).

```
def spam(x):
    return x+1 if x>=0 else 1/(1-x)
```

Now, with NumPy, the mantra is to avoid working on single values in favour of vectorisation, for performance. So I reckon something like this would be preferred:<sub>*As Leon remarks, the following is **wrong***</sub>

```
def eggs(x):
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    positive = x>=0
    y[positive] = x+1
    y[np.logical_not(positive)] = 1/(1-x)
    return y
```

(Correct me if I've missed something here, because frankly I find this very ugly.)

Now, of course `eggs` will *only* work if `x` is actually a NumPy array, because otherwise `x>=0` simply yields a single boolean, which can't be used for indexing (at least doesn't do the right thing).

Is there a good way to write code that looks more like `spam` but works idiomatic on Numpy arrays, or should I just use `vectorize(spam)`?

Comment: `y[positive]=x+1` is an error in your example. Indexing an array with a boolean array results (in general) in a shorter array (elements at indices with `False` values are removed).

Comment: Ah, you're right. Turns out I only ever tested that boolean-index pattern with constant expressions. So, this doesn't work anyway... but the question stands: how to do it correctly?

Comment: Maxim's answer shows how to correct `eggs()`

Comment: Is your input always float, or do you intentionally do an integer division in the second term?

Comment: @ChristophTerasa: well, that's not actually a realistic example. But, yeah, in my real application the input is always float.

Comment: Just a note from np.vectorize's docs: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). You'll get an array as the output even for plain number input, though.

```
def eggs(x):
    y = np.asarray(x)
    return np.where(y>=0, y+1, 1/(1-y))
```

This works for both arrays and plain numbers:

```
>>> eggs(5)
array(6.0)
>>> eggs(-3)
array(0.25)
>>> eggs(np.arange(-3, 3))
/home/praveen/.virtualenvs/numpy3-mkl/bin/ipython3:2: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
array([ 0.25      ,  0.33333333,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ])
>>> eggs(1)
/home/praveen/.virtualenvs/numpy3-mkl/bin/ipython3:3: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in long_scalars
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
array(2.0)
```

As ayhan remarks, this raises a warning, since `1/(1-x)` gets evaluated for the whole range. But a warning is just that: a warning. If you know what you're doing, you can ignore the warning. In this case, you're only choosing `1/(1-x)` from indices where it can never be `inf`, so you're safe.

Comment: This would raise a division by zero error for scalar 0 though because the else part is evaluated seperately.

Comment: @ayhan Excellent point! Let me add an `np.asarray` to fix that, so that where always gets an array, and then raises only a warning and not an error.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [numpy.asarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) (which is a no-op if the argument is already an numpy array) if I want to handle both numbers and numpy arrays

```
def eggs(x):
    x = np.asfarray(x)
    m = x>=0
    x[m] = x[m] + 1
    x[~m] = 1 / (1 - x[~m])
    return x
```

(here I used [asfarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asfarray.html) to enforce a floating-point type, since your function requires floating-point computations).

This is less efficient than your spam function for single inputs, and arguably uglier. However it seems to be the easiest choice.

EDIT: If you want to ensure that `x` is not modified (as pointed out by Leon) you can replace `np.asfarray(x)` by `np.array(x, dtype=np.float64)`, the array constructor copies by default.

Comment: Wouldn't this version of `eggs()` modify its input?

Comment: Yes it would, if the input is already a floating-point numpy array.